# Combining secure and unsecure environment on one PC

Tags: windows, security

I would like to create an environment for playing PC games with my friends. Most of the PC games run under windows. There are potential problems from a security prospective.

1. It may happen that one of my friends accidentally executes malicious code, for example by accidentally launching an application from the Internet.
2. A lot of PC games are running under windows, install a lot of additional software and require admin privileges, that will make my PC less secure
3. If some part of the game has admin privileges even creating a separate user under windows will not prevent a risk of running malicious code with admin privileges.

The most secure solution would be to use a separate PC. Unfortunately I don't have enough hardware, and need to split one PC for two environments - secure for work, banking etc. and less secure for gaming. I want to splitting my hard drive into 2 separate partitions, with separate windows installation. And use a bitlocker to prevent less secure windows installation to access to secure partition. Will this give an adequate level of security?

Comment: Perhaps; it is a matter of opinion. For a bit more security, I'd consider not just another partition, but another bootable drive. There are various ways that could be implemented, such as external USB drives, removable drive bays, etc.

Comment: Most applications do NOT require Administrator permissions to run, so you can use an unprivileged account, and run the majority of the applications you will want to run. BitLocker won’t and cannot be used in the way you describe. While it’s a security feature to protect data theft from physical access, while loaded and logged into Windows, all data is accessible by any application started by the user with permission to the encrypted data.

Comment: The removable drive bay is not possible because my computer does not have a slot for this device. The only option I have is to open the computer case and change the drive manually every time, and this is very inconvenient. A USB drive is much slower than an internal drive, at least 2 times slower, I have already looked at this option and done several tests.

Comment: I tried to install the Sims without admin rights, but I need EAappInstaller, which only works if you have administrator rights. And I will definitely have problems in the future when installing games, since they will often require administrator rights and I will need to spend a lot of time to get around this requirement. Bitlocker will protect the partition from data theft. Of course, if some malicious code is launched on the computer, it will be able to erase information on the bitlocker-encrypted partition, but it will not be able to read and steal it. I will also back up important data.